# Is something wrong with VeraCrypt?

Tags: debian, truecrypt

I didn't know where to ask this question, so I decided to ask it here.

I think all of you know TrueCrypt, and that something weird happened to it some time ago. In the light of those events at least two TC's forks were created: [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) and [ZuluCrypt](https://github.com/mhogomchungu/zuluCrypt).

Those who are using the Debian distro know that TrueCrypt never made its way to the official Debian repository. I don't know really why, but since TC is gone, let's focus on the two forks. For now [only ZuluCrypt is in the main Debian repository](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/zulucrypt). But what about VeraCrypt? There's no VeraCrypt in the [new package queue](https://ftp-master.debian.org/new.html). So it looks like it's not going to be added to the repository at all, and the question is why? Is something wrong with the software?

Comment: You could also consider asking it at [security.se]

Comment: @sashoalm No, this question isn't related to security. It's purely about the Debian project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ZuluCrypt is not a fork, it's [*"a front end to cryptsetup and tcplay and it allows easy management of encrypted block devices"*](https://github.com/mhogomchungu/zuluCrypt).

VeraCrypt on the other hand, is indeed a fork and thus [has parts under the strange TrueCrypt license](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=VeraCrypt%20License) and as such [won't be part the repository for the same reasons TrueCrypt wasn't](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=364034).